# Sorting a Content Search in Sharepoint 2016 on Prem doesn't work for SiteTitle

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to figure out a weird issue in my Content Search.   It just doesn't sort alphabetically by SiteTitle.

I've gone into Build Your Query, and selected the Sorting tab.  (Earlier, I went into Central Admin and made sure the property SiteTitle had Sortable Checked, and then I ran a full-crawl)  Here's my screen shot of showing my sort, but the results are not alphabetical by SiteTitle.    The seem to be sorted by the sites that are used the most.  [image]

Appreciate any suggestions on how to get this to sort properly.

Comment: Good day! Just wanted to ask some quick questions. One, is that a managed property or a crawled property. Two, if its a site property, can you confirm its pointing to the correct crawled property?

Comment: @KyleRogers-Brodeur - I logged into Central Admin, and checked.   SiteTitle is a Managed Property and it is mapped to OWS_SiteName

Comment: Darn. That seems all correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the **OWS_SiteName** managed property has checked **Sortable**.